# How to detect if a program (Process) is running and get its instance in a Windows 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am new to the world of Windows Universal Apps but I find it very interesting field so I wanted to start getting to know its capabilities.

I am currently an WPF .NET developer and I want to be able to check if a program is currently running and get its instance. In WPF I would do this with the help of [Process.GetProcessesByName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) but Process is not available in an Universal app. Is there a similar way of getting a process (running program's instance) in Windows 8.1 Universal App?

Comment: svchost.exe gets loaded for each running process that can even be seen in your task manager.

Comment: I am looking of doing in the code behind, can you give me a sample example code snippet of using the svchost.exe. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

System.Diagnostics.Process is not available in a UWP app. Those apps are sandboxed and are not allowed to look at the other processes running on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your using list:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Now you can get a list of the processes with the Process.GetProcesses() method, as seen in this example:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

Some interesting properties of the Process object that also may be required:

```
p.StartTime (Shows the time the process started)
p.TotalProcessorTime (Shows the amount of CPU time the process has taken)
p.Threads ( gives access to the collection of threads in the process)
```

Comment: When I try to use Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses(); it tells me that "The type or namespace 'Process' could not be found (are you missing an a using directive or an assembly reference)".

I tried to use this in an Window 8.1 universal solution(in the Windows 8.1 project not the phone one). I am aware I could use that code in a WPF application but I want to start to develop Universal apps. Is there a way I could use a WPF code in a Universal solution (probably via a portable code library maybe?)

Comment: yeah you should use "using System.Diagnostics" first as namespace.

Comment: Hi again. I am going crazy about this :). I am still unable to use the Process class in a Windows Universal App (Windows 8.1 project). No matter if I add the System.Diagnostics namespace, it simply does not contain a Process class. Here is a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/w9kmiiI.png) of what I am seeing.

I feel like I am trying to do something wrong in an Universal App :)

Comment: This anwer is not helpful and misleading. As Franklin M Gauer III points out in his answer, the `Process` class does not exist in UWP Apps.